# How to access dynamically created buttons in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, mean-stack

So, I am creating a quiz application where I have a scrollbar for questions and in that scrollbar I have buttons depending on the length of a question set. So I've created those buttons using *ngFor directive. Now what I want to do is whenever a user selects any option (mcq), the question buttons in the scrollbar should get highlighted in following way:

1. If user selects any option, then change the question button color to Green
2. If user skips the question, then change the question button color to Yellow

HTML Code for Question Scrollbar:

```
<div id="answer-buttons" class="ques-grid ">
            <button #navBarButton *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</button>
</div>
```

I'm have tried doing it by first accessing the buttons using ViewChild in ts file and then apply some logic, but it's not working, it is only changing the color of first button

```
@ViewChild('navBarButton',{ static: false }) navBarButton:ElementRef
//and in some function I've tried this logic
if(this.attemptedQuestionCount[this.currentQuestionIndex]==1){
  this.navBarButton.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "#228B22"
}
else{
  this.navBarButton.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "#FCF55F"
}
```

How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: ViewChild only get an unique element (the first) if you want get all you need use `@ViewChildren` -that return a QueryList of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for attemptedQuestionCount and change background color like this

```
<div id="answer-buttons" class="ques-grid ">
<button *ngFor="let question of questions; let i=index"
    [style.background-color]="attemptedQuestionCount[i] === 1 ? '#228B22' : '#FCF55F'">{{question}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add button tag as follows:

```
<button *ngFor="let question of questions; let i=index"
        [style.background-color]="attemptedQuestionCount[i] === 1 ? '#228B22' : '#FCF55F'">{{question}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the click handler directly to the button using

```
<button *ngFor="let item of items; let indexOfelement=index" 
      (click)="heyYouClicked(indexOfelement)">{{item}}</button>
```

And then in the component you place the handler

```
export class AppComponent {
  items = ["hello", "world"]

  heyYouClicked(index){
    console.log("you clicked " + index)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is something which I've already tried but doesn't work in my case

Comment: Maybe you have some other problematic code that isn't in your question? This example works on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/buttons-demo-kukw5

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ngClass` for simplicity.

```
<button #navBarButton *ngFor="let item of items" class="defualt_state" [ngClass]="{'new_state': (condition_here)}">{{item}}</button>
```

And in the stylesheet you can have the above class configured

```
.new_state { background-color: #228B22 !important }
```

And set the default color of the button this way

```
.default_state { background-color : #FCF55F}
```

So when the condition matches it will take the color specified in the `new_state` class or else will take the default color from `default_state` class.